# Null Value while passing json data to mvc 6 web application using knockout.js

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

Using the knockout js I tried to pass the json data to the mvc 6 controller action. I can see only null value to the dto parameter. If I use the same method in mvc 5 the value is assign to the dtos. What I am missing in the code.

```
var LoginAuthentication = {

    username: ko.observable(),
    password: ko.observable(),
    GetLoginAuthentication: function () {

        if ($("#loginAuthentication").valid()) {
            var self = this;
            var ajaxUrl = ApplicationRootUrl("LoginAuthentication", "Home");
            var UserCrendential = {
                UserName: self.username(),
                Password: self.password()
            };
            console.log(ko.toJSON(UserCrendential));
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: ajaxUrl,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                data: ko.toJSON(UserCrendential),
                success: function (data) {
                },
                error: function (err) {

                }

            });
        }
    }
};
```

Here is the dto class

```
public class LoginAuthenticationModel
    {
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
```

Below is the controller method.

```
 public void LoginAuthentication(LoginAuthenticationModel loginAuthenticationModel)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {

                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {


                }
            }
        }
```

The output result of the code 
[image]

The result of browser inspect
[image]

Comment: does UserCrendential have some value?

Comment: What does the json look like after ko.toJSON(UserCrendential) ? Can you inspect it with browser tools and post the object?

Comment: `console.log(UserCrendential)` and check what it has?

Comment: I have updated the question please have a look

Comment: Have you tried passing in the `UserCredential` object in to the ajax call directly, rather than the stringified value? That bit doesn't look right to me.

Comment: I have tried JSON.stringify(UserCredential) but still I can find the null value in the controller method. This method is not working in mvc 6 however same method is working fine in mvc 5. If I post data from google crome extension postman without content type the data is mapped to the dtos.I removed the content type from ajax call still I am not able to get the data in controller action

Comment: I think he meant you to try just ```data: UserCredential```. jquery does stringify the json by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Include `[FromBody]` in your controller to read json data from request body as

```
public void LoginAuthentication([FromBody]LoginAuthenticationModel loginAuthenticationModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the issues I still get the null value from the ajax

Answer (score 0):

The below line solve the problem however I dont known is it a right solution.
I remove the below code from ajax call 
                dataType: "json"

and changes the data as loginAuthenticationModel without converting to anything

```
var LoginAuthentication = {

    username: ko.observable(),
    password: ko.observable(),
    GetLoginAuthentication: function () {

        if ($("#loginAuthentication").valid()) {
            var self = this;
            var ajaxUrl = ApplicationRootUrl("LoginAuthentication", "Home");
            var loginAuthenticationModel = {
                UserName: self.username(),
                Password: self.password()
            };
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: ajaxUrl,
                dataType: "json",
                data: loginAuthenticationModel,
                success: function (data) {
                },
                error: function (err) {

                }

            });
        }
    }
};
```